# Get text bounding box relative to the canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

`Paint.getTextBounds()` gets the bounds of the text relative to itself, I need to get the bounding box of the text on the canvas it was drawn, is there a simple way to get that?

Comment: The idea is that you use that before you draw the text, so the two are equivalent.  What problem are you having with it that you need to check afterwards?

Comment: @GabeSechan draw a few words on a canvas and then I'd like to map the position of those word so I could respond to click on them, I need the coordinates of the drawn words on the canvas.

Comment: When you draw them, you draw them to a position.  Save that position.  That's the baseline.  Then use paint.ascent and paint.descent to tell how high above the baseline it goes, and add the width from the bounds to tell how far left/right to go.

Comment: @Calc just call Rect.offset(x, y)